# When I use lsblk to see the disk size, it is smaller than the vendor give

Tags: linux, disk

I use lsblk to see the disk(raid0) size.

```
# lsblk -b 
sdy     65:128  0 2399812976640  0 disk /data1
...
# lsblk     
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdy     65:128  0  2.2T  0 disk /data1
...
```

`lsblk` shows 2.2T is smaller than the vendor give "2.4T". Some people say that the vendor use 10 hex to measure the disk size. But `lsblk -b` show 2399812976640 is smaller than 2400000000000.

Comment: +/-0.01% not ok for you?

Comment: But for /dev/sda(raid 1), lsblk show 1199638052864 while vendor mark 1.2T. (1200000000000-1199638052864)*1.0/1200000000000 ~= 0.03%